# Why `wc -c` always count 1 more character?

Tags: command-line-interface

in `tmp` I type a single character,but `wc -c` shows `2`,why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because newlines are characters too. Tell your text editor to not add one at the end of the file. No, I don't know how.

Comment: as a workaround, you could count newlines with `wc -l` and substract them from the count of `wc -c`. If you are counting directly from a piped / redirected output, consider using [tee](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) for splitting it.

Comment: This is a very unhelpful answer. Why is it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 17):

If the character count provided by `wc -c` is +1 more than expected, its input likely contains a newline `\n` character.

One way to handle this is to use `tr` to delete newlines, then you can count the characters.

Standard behavior:

```
echo HELLO | wc -m
# result: 6
echo -n HELLO | wc -m
# result: 5
```

To show the count of newline characters found:

```
echo HELLO | wc -l
# result: 1
echo -n HELLO | wc -l
# result: 0
```

Strip the newline character and count characters:

```
echo HELLO | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
# result: 5
```

Strip the newline character (and possible returns with `\r`) and count characters for an input file:

```
tr -d '\n\r' < input.txt | wc -m
```

Note that the examples above use `echo`, which adds the newline `\n` character.

Comment: also `printf "hello"` vs `printf "hello\n"`

Comment: @Aaron makes a great point. If you're able to use printf instead of echo, you eliminate the newlines altogether. The echo command adds a newline character.

Comment: `echo -n` was super useful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a similar suggestion to the-wabbit's for my calculations.

> as a workaround, you could count newlines with wc -l and substract
>   them from the count of wc -c.

```
function num_chars () {
    # echo -e tells echo to honor certain sequences like \n
    chars=$(echo -e "${1}" | wc -c)
    lines=$(echo -e "${1}" | wc -l)
    real_chars=$(echo "$chars - $lines" | bc)
    echo "$real_chars"
}

num_chars "hello Dolly"
11 #Result
num_chars "hello
dolly"
11 #Result
num_chars "hello \nDolly"
11 #Result
```